# How to remove medium size class in gravity form for input tag?

Tags: filters, forms, plugin-gravity-forms

I want to remove classes or replace class name with custom class names on a Gravity Forms email `input` field.

I found this solution:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_css_class_3', 'custom_class', 10, 3  );
function custom_class( $classes, $field, $form ) {
    if ($field->type == 'email' ) {
        $classes .= ' form-control formbox';
    }


    return $classes;
}
```

But after running this code from `function.php` it did not work. 
This  is the output after it's run:

```
<li id="field_3_3" class="gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible form-control formbox">
  <label class="gfield_label" for="input_3_3">email</label>
  <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_email">
    <input name="input_3" id="input_3_3" value="" class="medium" aria-invalid="false" type="email">
  </div>
</li>
```

This solution replaces CSS classes for the `li` tags. I'm looking for a way to change class name for `input` tags only.